# SQL: select items with number of comments AND latest comment date

Tags: mysql, left-join

I want to display the items with the number of comments and the date of the last comment, each item.

```
SELECT item.*, 
  count(comments.itemid) AS commentcount, 
  comments.created AS commentcreated 
FROM table_items AS item 
LEFT JOIN table_comments AS comments ON (comments.itemid = item.id) 
WHERE item.published=1 
GROUP BY item.id 
ORDER BY item.created DESC
```

Now the commentcreated value is the date of the first comment: I want the last comment. Order by doesn't work on the LEFT JOIN. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT item.*, 
  count(comments.itemid) AS commentcount, 
  max(comments.created) AS commentcreated 
FROM table_items AS item 
LEFT JOIN table_comments AS comments ON (comments.itemid = item.id) 
WHERE item.published=1 
GROUP BY item.id 
ORDER BY item.created DESC
```

You need to tell MySQL which of the dates in the group to use with max(), min() or one of the other aggregating functions.

Comment: Yes, great thanks! This works! But what if I want to select the title of the latest comment?

Comment: I think that is a different question.